# How to access Night Light settings on Samsung

Tags: samsung

I just upgraded my Pixel 2 to a Samsung Fold 2. My Pixel was using Night Light and it was set to go on at 8pm and off at 6am. The Samsung Smart Switch app helpfully copied these settings over; however, Samsung doesn't use Night Light. Samsung has their own software called "Eye Comfort Shield" (disabled). So, now at 8pm, my phone simply goes dark. Completely black and unusable until 6am.

I can probably factory reset the Samsung and recopy from the old phone, but that seems excessive. Is there a way to add Night Light or just wipe those Night Light settings?

Comment: May be possible via `adb shell settings put secure ...` see this question for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50144828/150978

Comment: @Robert That's a great idea. If those settings are all .xml I could probably have grep'ed for the start and stop times. Sadly, I went ahead and wiped the phone and cloned the stuff I care about with android-studio instead of the Samsung app.